# List all data from table by date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm curious to find a solution for this but couldn't find anything relatable and useful so far.

I have a table `Transaction`:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "transaction_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "wallet_name", nullable = false)
private String walletName;

@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
@Min(value = 0, message = "Please, insert a positive amount")
private Double amount;

private String note;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "date")
private LocalDate date;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id", nullable = false)
private Wallet wallet;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "transaction_type", columnDefinition = "ENUM('EXPENSE', 'INCOME')")
private TransactionType transactionType;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "expense_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('FOOD_AND_DRINK', 'SHOPPING', 'TRANSPORT', 'HOME'," +
        " 'BILLS_AND_FEES', 'ENTERTAINMENT', 'CAR', 'TRAVEL', 'FAMILY_AND_PERSONAL', 'HEALTHCARE'," +
        " 'EDUCATION', 'GROCERIES', 'GIFTS', 'BEAUTY', 'WORK', 'SPORTS_AND_HOBBIES', 'OTHER')")
private ExpenseCategories expenseCategories;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "income_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('SALARY', 'BUSINESS', 'GIFTS', 'EXTRA_INCOME', 'LOAN', 'PARENTAL_LEAVE', 'INSURANCE_PAYOUT', 'OTHER')")
private IncomeCategories incomeCategories;
```

Now, to display that data on Thymeleaf I created controller with model that I'm passing on Thymeleaf .

And that looks like this:

```
@GetMapping("/userTransactions/{user_id}")
public String getUserTransactions(@PathVariable("user_id") long user_id, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);
    model.addAttribute("transactions", transactionService.findDistinctIdByUserId(user_id));
    return "transactions";
}
```

As you can see, `Transaction` is connected with `User` so user actually can create a `Transaction`, and on that controller I'm just getting all transaction from each User and this is how I display it on `Thymeleaf`:

```
<div th:each="transactions : ${transactions}">
    <h2>Amount: <span th:text="${transactions.amount}"></span></h2>
    <br>
    <h2>Note: <span th:text="${transactions.note}"></span></h2>
    <br>
    <h2>Date: <span th:text="${transactions.date}"></span></h2>
    <br>
    <h2>Wallet name: <span th:text="${transactions.walletName}"></span></h2>
    <br>
    <h2>Expense Category: <span th:text="${transactions.expenseCategories}"></span></h2>
    <br>
    <h2>IncomeCategory: <span th:text="${transactions.incomeCategories}"></span></h2>
</div>
```

Don't mind the way I formatted it, point is that works fine so far, I got all data displayed on page but I want to achieve one thing:

As you can see, while creating transaction user also pick a date, and what I want?

Lets say user have two transactions for today, I mean `18/01/2023`

I want to have a heading for example like `<div` and to pass today date and each transaction from today, and below down for example `15/01/2023` because user also have a transactions on that date.

This is an example, as you can see I have today section because user made a transaction on today date, also for yesterday and then back on January 14, so I want to separate transactions for each that like that.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ecf9.png)

Sorry for SS, I tried to add code snippet but cant find option on this updated SO.

I don't know from where to start, I found some options like to sort from ascending and descending order date but I want to avoid something like that and to give my best to achieve this. So any resource, tutorial or any help here will be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break it up by date, you should do that in the Java beforehand.  Instead of passing a `List<Transaction>`, you should pass a `List<TransactionGroup>` where a TransactionGroup contains all the transactions for a day. It might look something like:

```
class TransactionGroup {
  private LocalDate date;
  private List<Transaction> transactions;
  /* Getters and setters */
}
```

Then your html becomes simple.

```
<div th:each="group : ${transactionGroup}">
    <h1 th:text="${group.date}" />

    <div th:each="transaction : ${group.transactions}">
        <h2>Amount: <span th:text="${transactions.amount}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Note: <span th:text="${transactions.note}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Wallet name: <span th:text="${transactions.walletName}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>Expense Category: <span th:text="${transactions.expenseCategories}"></span></h2><br>
        <h2>IncomeCategory: <span th:text="${transactions.incomeCategories}"></span></h2>
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats sounds good and looks like a good solution, but I'm confused a bit. I added class like in your example and also updated a Thymeleaf part, m I missing something? Do I need to update controller also? Since page is blank, I mean I cant see transactions like before

Comment: You have to fill up the TransactionGroup with Transactions and Dates.

Comment: I tried like this `transactionGroup.setTransactions(transaction.getAmount(), transaction.getNote(), transaction.getWalletName());
` but I'm getting error that `walletName` cannot be null

Comment: Here is the github repo if that can be helpful https://github.com/sjankdev/budgettracker-final

Comment: When the OP is wisely using the modern `LocalDate` class for a date, why are you using the long outdated and badly designed `Date` class that despite its name cannot represent a date?

Comment: Idk if you are ironic, date class is not primary now, I want to solve this probem :((

Comment: Just to update. I managed to successfully save transaction like before but now with filling TransactionGroup and that works fine, but data is not displayed on page

Comment: Did you add the transaction groups to the model? `model.addAttribute("transactionGroup", transactionGroup);`

Comment: Can you help me a bit more @Metroids